# ChartJS: Update tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I'm having a chart build with ChartJS. I'm including datasets.label in multipleTooltipLabel template and facing an update issue. When changing a datasets.label and running `chart.update()` the tooltip is not updated. I created a [JSFiddle demonstrating the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/sv760bp5/1/).

The code I use to include datasets label in tooltip:

```
var options = {
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%>: <%= value + ' %' %>"
};
```

Beside that option I followed [ChartJS usage example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart-example-usage) for Line charts.

Change label and update chart:

```
myNewChart.datasets[0].label = 'updated label';
myNewChart.update();
```

Label shown in tooltip is not updated...

I had a look in ChartJS source code and figured out that [`showTooltip` function](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/3f2119526d929ea22f8c971c47a242b4a958cdda/Chart.js#L1003-L1144) is called with a `ChartElements` array which was not updated.

Update: I might cached the issue. `label` of `dataset` is [set on each `point` element](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/3f2119526d929ea22f8c971c47a242b4a958cdda/Chart.js#L2369) and not updated if it changes. `showTooltip` used this "cached" dataset label when drawing a tooltip. Perhaps this should not be a question on StackOverflow but a bug report for ChartJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
myNewChart.datasets[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
  point.datasetLabel = 'updated label';
});
```

This might also be the way it should be done. Chart.js documentation of [`update` method](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-prototype-methods) says you should set `myLineChart.datasets[0].points[2].value = 50;` to change the value. That's confusing cause on creation dataset expects the values in `data` property. `points` is generated by `Chart.Line` Class on init. Naming may be different for other chart types (eg. it's `bars` for a bar chart).

I'm not quite sure if `myLineChart.datasets[0].label` value is used somewhere or if could be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve your problem by changing the original data object (data.datasets[0].label='updated label') then running myNewChart.initialize(data).

Answer (score 0):

```
var option = {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (context) {
                    //console.log(context);
                    label = 'new string ' + context.label + ', ' + context.dataIndex;
                    return label;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

myChart.options = option;
```

*ToolTips* **/** *Points* **Events** are configurable with *chartJS* **options**...

[image]

Find more here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html